# How to export defined polygon and FeatureCollection points from Google Earth Engine JavaScript code editor to Python API in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

]I am new to GEE. I have written RandomForest code in JavaScript code Editor but our Supervisor is asking me to convert that code to Python API. I am trying to do it in Jupyter Notebook and I want to import my Geometry imports from GEE Code Editor to Python API but I don't know how. How can I export that from the JavaScript GEE code editor to Python, as it is required for submission?

Update: I am trying to say that I want to use these geometry imports in my Python API as our supervisor is asking for it.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to do this would be to use the "Show generated code" button:

[image]

A second option would be to copy it from the source code, which you can find in `https://earthengine.googlesource.com/path/to/your/repository`

Once you find your repository in https://earthengine.googlesource.com, you can open your script and you will see that the script contains a header such as:

```js
/**** Start of imports. If edited, may not auto-convert in the playground. ****/
var geometry = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([-103.5056640625, 43.9490885608096]);
/***** End of imports. If edited, may not auto-convert in the playground. *****/
```

with all of your script imports, including geometries.

See https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/playground#script_manager_scripts_tab and https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/playground#imports for more information.

Comment: Of course, you will need to remove the `/* */` comments and the `var` definition, and other minor modifications (especially if it is a multi-line definition) to make it valid python code.